# I want replace url use htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, replace

How to replace url use htaccess ? My url :

```
domain.com/xem/?i=example
```

i want replace to

```
domain.com/xem/example
```

I want to replace these links without error, please help me!

Answer (score 1):

An internal rewrite to `/?i=example` makes little sense (I assume that is what you actually ask, `domain.com?i=example` makes even less sense, or do you *really* have a folder named`domain.com` on your system?). Instead you should rewrite to your actual router script or logic, so something like

```
RewriteEngine on
RequestCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RequestCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?(\w+)/?$ /index.php?i=$1 [END]
```

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: My url : https://aniraw.net/xemphim/?i=go-toubun-no-hanayome&play=1 , i will to remove ?i= and ?play=

Comment: So there are two questions you will need to answer: 1. what resource will get requested internally with the rewriting? A folder cannot process an argument, so you need to have some script or executable that gets requested. I used `index.php` as an example above, you can have something else, but there needs to be _something_ . And 2. what happens to the `play` argument, where does it's value come from?